# Merging sections of lines with same geometry in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, merge

I have a series of bus routes with the frequency/hour attached in QGIS.

The idea is to combine the frequencies on routes with more than one bus to have an overall bus frequency for the sections of road the buses share.

Is there a method to do this short of manually selecting routes?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. It is always helpful to attach some example data so the question is easier to understand and the help may be more to the point. If I got this right, you want to count, how many lines with how many busses per hour are frequenting your roads and display the total "busses per hour" count?

Comment: `sum("Frequency_Field", group_by:= geom_to_wkt($geometry))`